# Warning from HTML/Javascript Facebook application

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-opengraph

When I put my application link in the Object Debugger, I get this warning:
    **Extraneous Property** Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:site_url.

I don't have any Meta tags in my code. I don't know how to fix an extraneous property that I haven't even defined. Any ideas how to fix that?

This is the only script being called in my code right now. I paired down all the other stuff and with this I still got the error. Although *not* when I put in the link for the canvas page, only with the link to the app itself.

```
FB.init({
    appId  : '###',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    channelUrl  : 'mysite.com/channel.html', // Custom channel URL
    oauth : true // enables OAuth 2.0
});
```

Comment: are you making a GET or POST request? and what kind (get/post) does your URL handler (Servlet) accept?

Comment: I've got only one script being called. Too big for a comment. I'll put it in the original question.

Comment: Ok, try out the suggestion in my answer below and I think it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`channelUrl  : 'mysite.com/channel.html'`

to

`channelUrl  : '//www.mysite.com/channel.html'`

Ref - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: It didn't get rid of the error message, but it _did_ stop the error from happening when I try to actually go to the site.